# What package contains docbook2x-texi?

Tags: compiling, git

I'm building `git` and get the following error:

> ```
>     DB2TEXI user-manual.texi
> /bin/sh: 2: docbook2x-texi: not found
> ```

How do I install `docbook2x-texi`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `docbook2x-texi`:

```
sudo apt-get -y install docbook2x
```

That's all I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

In synaptic you can search for "docbook2x-texi" and select the "Description and name" search option.